# BIRT Dynamic XML with parameters

Tags: html, xml, parameters, birt

I would like to have a dynamic XML data source with parameters.
I have a FileName textbox parameter and in the beforeOpen on the Data Source I put `this.setExtensionProperty("FILELIST", params["FileName"].value);`
but the other parameters have blanks
[image]

I update the FileName parameter with a correct XML file location `C:\Users\1122335\Desktop\dss_Sat14084.xml` and I thought if I could refresh the report with the correct XML file location it would populated the other parameters.

```
<input type="button" value="Refresh"
onclick="reloadPage()" >

<form name="input" onSubmit="return reloadPage();">
<script type="text/javascript">
function reloadPage() {
var temp = new String(location.href);
var targetURL = new String();

if(temp.indexOf("__overwrite=") != -1 ){
targetURL = temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf("&__overwrite") -1);
}else{
targetURL = temp;
}

targetURL += "&__overwrite=true&FileName=<VALUE-OF>params["FileName"]</VALUE-OF>";

location.replace(targetURL);

return false;
}

</script>
</form>
```

But when I refresh the report it changes the FileName parameter to this `C:UsersJ2335Desktopdss_Sat14084.xml`

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do something like this. I would appreciate all the help possible.

Comment: Have you tried using / instead of \ ?

Comment: @hvb I did it a different way and just made a hyperlink that drill through to the same report with the FileName parameters. Thanks for the suggestion though